# Porque meu DriverManager retorna null pointer?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, servlet

**PostgreSQL 9.4**

1. Executo minha classe `Noticias()`.
2. Dentro do método `public static void main()` da classe `Noticias()`
   é feito a chamada de um método `getConexao()`;
3. Quando executo o `pagecontroller?=p=noticias` no navegador ele me retorna `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
4. Quando executo a classe `Noticias()` no Eclipse ele não retorna um
   ponteiro null e faz conexão com o banco de dados sem nenhum erro.

**Obs.:** Dentro do diretório WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ estou com a lib postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar porém mesmo assim quando faço uso da minha classe `Noticias()` pelo navegador não é feito a conexão com o banco de dados, meu servidor do Tomcat está executando pela IDE Eclipse.

```
public class PageController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PageController() {
       super();
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Chamou o metodo GET");

    String pagina = request.getParameter("p");


    if (pagina.equals("noticias")){
        Noticias noticias = new Noticias();
        List<Noticias> lista = noticias.getNoticias();
        request.setAttribute("noticias", lista);
        RequestDispatcher saida = request.getRequestDispatcher("noticias.jsp");
        saida.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Segue classe `Noticias()`:

```
public class Noticias{

int grid;
String topico;
String conteudo;
int usuario;
Date data;

public Noticias(){
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Noticias> noticias = getNoticias();
}

public static List<Noticias> getNoticias(){
    List<Noticias> noticia_list = new ArrayList<Noticias>();
    String sql = "SELECT * from NOTICIAS";

    Connection conexao = null;

    try {
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base", "postgres", "postgres");
        System.out.print("Conexao com o banco de dados efetuada com sucesso!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Erro durante a conexao com o banco de dados!");
    }

    PreparedStatement prepared_sql = null;

    try {
        prepared_sql = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ResultSet result = prepared_sql.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            Noticias noticia = new Noticias();
            noticia.setGrid(result.getInt("grid"));
            noticia.setTopico(result.getString("topico"));
            noticia.setConteudo(result.getString("conteudo"));
            noticia.setUsuario(result.getInt("usuario"));
            noticia.setData(result.getDate("data"));

            noticia_list.add(noticia);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return noticia_list;
}
```

Comment: Inclua o log com a exceção também, mas provavelmente é por que você cria conexão no `main`, ele não será executado se você não chamá-lo ou não executar como uma aplicação java. Não sei como está sua aplicação, mas tente chamar o `getConexao()` em `getNoticias()`

Comment: Mas você fez o deploy do jar do postgree no seu tomcat?

Comment: Vou fazer o que você disse @BrunoCésar para ver se funciona.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck não fiz o deploy, vou verificar isso também.

Comment: @BrunoCésar coloquei tudo em apenas um método chamado `getNoticias()`, dentro desse método ele tenta fazer a conexão, porém sem sucesso!

Comment: Inclua a *stack trace*, fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: @BrunoCésar obrigado por tentar ajudar, o problema foi solucionado... obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica se o `.jar` do driver está no diretório `/WEB-INF/lib`.

<strike>Você está fazendo `pagecontroller?=p=noticias` mesmo?</strike>

Possui 2 iguais nesse parâmetro, o que zoa totalmente. Faça

```
pagecontroller?p=noticias
```

O `nullpointer` me parece ser por ele não encontrar o `getParameter("p")` ai tu faz `.equals` resultando no **erro**.

#### UPDATE

Adicione `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` antes da sua conexão:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
    conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base", "postgres", "postgres");
    System.out.print("Conexao com o banco de dados efetuada com sucesso!");

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    System.out.println("Erro durante a conexao com o banco de dados!");
}
```

Comment: Já verifiquei e está entrando no if, o problema é na hora de buscar a conexão...

Comment: @LuizRicardoCardoso poste o código da classe Noticias ocultando informações sigilosas

Comment: Editei o post, lembrando que a conexão é retornada quando eu executo pelo Eclipse (Run java application), porém no navegador o ponteiro vem null.

Comment: @LuizRicardoCardoso Atualizei minha resposta, experimenta e mostre o log se der algum

Comment: Coloquei um try Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); e caiu no catch. O erro continua o mesmo, retornando um ponteiro null.

Comment: @LuizRicardoCardoso Você colocou o `.jar` no `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Eu troquei meu workspace e esqueci de colocar, com o `.jar` dentro da pasta lib funciona... O `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` força a execução do driver correto?

Comment: Em algumas versões anteriores precisava fazer isso pra inicializar, mas o principal motivo é pra verificar se existe a classe no seu ambiente

Comment: Solucionou seu problema?

Comment: Sim o problema foi solucionado, obrigado!